# Close Couchbase connection once entries have been saved

Tags: node.js, couchbase, faker

I use Faker to insert some dummy data into Couchbase database. It seems to me that I need to close the connection on the insertion operations complete because now when it inserts all the entries, the app keeps being active, doesn't return me to console.
How to manage it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To close connection to bucket you can use `bucket.shutdown()` function. See example below:

```
couchbase.connect(config, function(err, bucket) {
  ... // do some work
  bucket.shutdown(); // shutdown connection on work done
});
```

Link to [test](https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/blob/master/test/shutdown.js) for this function on github.

Comment: This is now `disconnect`. https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/blob/5bd5a0bcc500df3bac8db54f5682d696b21b1346/lib/bucket.js#L296

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated example snippet for 2.x versions of the Node Couchbase SDK that uses `disconnect()`. Idea is that when you're done with all your operations on a connection, shut it down:

```
var bucket = myCluster.openBucket(bucketName, function (err) {
    if (err) {/*handle error*/}
    bucket.get(someId, function (err, res) {
        bucket.disconnect();
        //do stuff with results
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
process.exit();
```

which can get you out of the process.

I do not know about the couchbase module specifically.

Comment: The Couchbase Node SDK open it own call back and stays open. This is due to the fact that the client needs an open connection to the cluster (multiple nodes) to get/set the data, but also to be alerted when the cluster topology changes.

So as said before you can shutdown the connection using the shutdown() call or simply call the process.exit() as Adam explained.

This is what is done in the Couchbase Node SDK test suite:
https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/blob/master/tests/setup.js#L53